# Java ((4-2) / 4) = 0.0 not 0.5 after casting as double

Tags: java

This method has myNumSides equal to 4, myNumSides is a user-inputted. After myAngle being casted as a double it still returns 0.0 instead of 0.5. Why is this?

```
public double getMyAngle()
    {
        int n;
        n = myNumSides;

        double myAngle = (double) ((n - 2) / n);

        return myAngle;
    }
```

## Output

```
Please enter number of sides => 4
Please enter length of each side => 100

Your polygon has 4 sides.
Each side of your polygon has a length of 100.0.
The angle of each vertex is 0.0.
```

Comment: You're casting the result of integer division, not the integers - by the time you cast, the truncation has already happened ;)

Comment: `((n - 2) / n)` is integer arithmetic, and the result is 0. Conversion to double is too late.

Comment: cast to double before divide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When java executes `double myAngle = (double) ((n - 2) / n);`, It will first do the division operation and then do the casting operation. In the division operation you are dividing an Integer by an another Integer. So the result of this division also will be an Integer. In your case case, 2/4 = 0.

Correct code would be do the casting first and then division.

```
double myAngle = ((double)(n - 2) / n);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the correct answer, you would have to do the following:

```
double myAngle = ((n - 2.0) / n);
```

OR

```
double myAngle =  ((n - 2) / (double)n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cast a zero to a double, it's still a zero. What you do with the result has no effect on how it's computed.

Answer (score 0):

You have already performed the math as an `int`, you then cast that `int` to a `double`. This widens the value but does not restore the lost precision to the previously computed value, I suggest you just make `n` a `double` like

```
public double getMyAngle() {
    double n = myNumSides;
    return ((n - 2) / n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can change your code to:

```
public double getMyAngle()
    {
        int n;
        n = myNumSides;
        double myAngle = (double)(n - 2)/n;
        return myAngle;
    }
```

==================
then the answer should be correct!